# Gradle fails to find method useModule() in a Java project

Tags: java, gradle

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'TEST'.

> Could not find method useModule() for arguments [net.minecraftforge:ForgeGradle:4.0, settings_8hclc1ejt8ciucnqbipmjtw7e$_run_closure1$_closure3$_closure6$_closure7@5261ee0d] on object of type org.gradle.plugin.management.internal.DefaultPluginResolveDetails.

```
my settings.gradle:
```

```
    pluginManagement {
        repositories {
            mavenCentral()

            maven { url = "https://maven.minecraftforge.net/" }
            maven { url = "https://jitpack.io/" }
        }
        resolutionStrategy {
            eachPlugin {
                if (requested.id.id == "net.minecraftforge.gradle.forge") {
                    useModule("net.minecraftforge:ForgeGradle:4.0") {
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    rootProject.name = 'TEST'
```

It seems to be a problem with "useModule" but i dont know what is wrong i am on a VM trying to compile
might be a dependency problem?

Thanks in advance!

Prob is a dependency problem i am on a windows VM

Comment: Your title would apply to every question on this site. Be specific. Mention the *problem.*

Comment: Terrible title. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to go out on a limb and suggest removing the `{}` after the `useModule`.  For example:

```
if (requested.id.id == "net.minecraftforge.gradle.forge") {
    useModule("net.minecraftforge:ForgeGradle:4.0") {
    }
}
```

Remove them and you get:

```
if (requested.id.id == "net.minecraftforge.gradle.forge") {
    useModule("net.minecraftforge:ForgeGradle:4.0")
}
```

There is no `useModule` method that takes 2 arguments which those curly braces would mean a Closure as a 2nd parameter.  That's probably why it's failing.